# Can't take the list of users that belong to a group to the html form

Tags: django

I will really need your help over here. I think I have read all the relevant responses to my problem but I cannot figure out how it works.

I would like to choose from the html form in django some users that belong to a specific group.

I created my model "Task", which is below:

```
class Task(models.Model):

Taskdetails = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
asset = models.ForeignKey('Asset', null=True)
failure = models.ForeignKey('Failure', null=True)
Created_task_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True)
employee = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", null = True)


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)
```

The django form is:

```
class TaskForm (ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Task
    fields = ('Taskdetails', 'asset', 'failure', 'employee',)
```

The view is:

```
def task_new(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    task_form = TaskForm(request.POST)
    subtask_form=SubtaskForm(request.POST)
    task_form.employee = User.objects.filter(groups__name='supervisor')
    if task_form.is_valid() and subtask_form.is_valid():
        task = task_form.save()
        subtask = subtask_form.save(commit=False)
        task.Created_task_date = timezone.now()
        task_form.employee = User.objects.filter(groups__name='supervisor')
        task.save()
        subtask.task=task
        subtask.Created_subtask_date = timezone.now()
        subtask.save()
        return redirect('great_job')
else:
    task_form = TaskForm()
    subtask_form = SubtaskForm()
return render(request, 'TaskTrace/task_new.html', {'task_form': task_form, 'subtask_form':subtask_form})
```

And the relative html is

```
    {% block content %}
<div>
 <h1>New Task</h1>
<form method="POST" class="task-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Equipment with failure: {{ task_form.asset }}<br><br>
    Failure Description:  {{ task_form.failure }} <br><br>
    Task Details: {{ task_form.Taskdetails }} <br><br>
      Employee: {{ task_form.employee }}


    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Open</button>
</form>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

I created in the django-admin 3 users. Two of them belongs to a the group "supervisor". I would like to be shown in the template only these two users that belong to this particular group. On the contrary, all the users are thrown in the form.

Can anyone please help me to move forward? I have stuck for 3 days in this particular point.

Thanks in advnance!

Answer (score 0):

On your view when creating the form you have to do something like this:

```
task_form  = TaskForm()
task_form.fields["employee"].queryset = User.objects.filter(group__name="supervisor")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Instead of your second line I have written:                             `task_form.employee = User.objects.filter(groups__name='supervisor')`        When I write in Python console, it shows me the groups. I suspect that something is wrong withe the left part of the command `task_form.employee`